# JAVA - Count members on an arraylist which has a common string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an `ArrayList` from recursively crawling through a directory

```
[project1_john_document1, project1_john_document2, project2_jose_document1, project2_jose_document2, project3_juan_document1, ...... ]
```

I am trying to count the instances for each project to get the following output

```
project1 = 3, 
project2 = 2,
project3 = 1, ....
```

What I have done is to Iterate through the list but somehow I am stuck as to how to get the "project1" as a common project, as there are numerous project names on the directory. I tried splitting the string using the split("_"), but since I am entirely noob, I couldn't get the logic of classifying the different project name.

Newbie in java here and sorry for the vague phrasing of my question.

Comment: if you would show us your code, we can tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: Take a look on regex, if you want to find that pattern inside your array, and when a match occurs, count it.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get all the projects names, then you can use a Map for example :

```
String str = "[project1_john_document1, project1_john_document2, project2_jose_document1, project2_jose_document2, project3_juan_document1]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("project\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String project;
while (m.find()) {
    project = m.group();
    if (map.containsKey(project )) {
        map.put(project , map.get(project ) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(project , 1);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
}
```

***Outputs***

```
project2    2
project1    2
project3    1
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cqkoW0/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is simple - projectNumber before "_" this one do this job:

```
 Map<String, Long> projectNumbers = Arrays.asList("project1_john_document1", "project1_john_document2", "project2_jose_document1", "project2_jose_document2", "project3_juan_document1")
                .stream().map(s -> s.split("_")[0])
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the count of how many `project1`, `project2` and so on folders you have, you could achieve it with the following code:

```
    String[] names = {"project1_john_document1", "project1_john_document2", "project2_jose_document1", "project2_jose_document2", "project3_juan_document1"};
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (String entry : names) {
        String project = entry.split("_")[0];
        int count = counts.containsKey(project) ? counts.get(project) : 0;
        counts.put(project, count + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(counts);
    // prints: {project2=2, project1=2, project3=1}
```

As the other answers mentioned, you could use regex, streams, etc. to do similar things. But the basic logic is the same: for each folder, get the root name, increment the counter in a map. If you're a beginner, I'd probably get my head around the most basic flow first before diving into slightly more complex things (e.g., streams).

Answer (score 1):

define your custom Function that converts your string names into something more simpler to be compared, then collect that

```
List<String> myL = Arrays.asList("project1_john_document1", "project1_john_document2",
            "project2_jose_document1", "project2_jose_document2", "project3_juan_document1");
Function<String, String> myFRegex = t -> {
        return t.substring(0, t.indexOf("_"));
    };
Map<String, Long> primeFactorCount = myL.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myFRegex, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(primeFactorCount);
```

the output can look like:

> {project2=2, project1=2, project3=1}

Answer (score 0):

This is the "Longest common substring problem". You can find an algorithm (in pseudo code) on the following article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem